# How to uninstall GridinSoft Anti-Malware installed through wine?

Tags: linux-mint, uninstall, free-software

When I try to uninstall through wine it only opens the installer again.
[image]

[image]

when i try to uninstall it with the applet searcher nothing happens either
[image]

I'm using linux Mint 19.2 Tina.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved it. I used the first option in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713932/how-to-uninstall-a-game-which-is-not-letting-me-uninstall-it) answer and also went to
`~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs` and deleted the program folder.
After that, wine uninstaller still enumerated the program in the list, but when trying to remove it again it didn't find any files hence asking if I wanted to remove it from there too.

Now it no longer appears when I search for it.